# What's the requirement of R version to build SparkR component?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

What's R version used to build sparkR in spark1.6.1 ,2.1.1,2.2.0 respectively?Should I use a specific R version to build different sparkR version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific version requirement. SparkR code is relatively limited and depends only on high level and stable language features. Any recent R version will do fine.